# Get Count of json key using Java Stream

Tags: java, java-8, stream

I have a json object that looks like this

```
 [{
                "startAt": 1617605301292,
                "endAt": 1617605317095,
                "duration": 15803,
                "selection": {
                    "selected.Speed": "0",
                    "selected.Low": "65535",
                    "selected.Fast": "7173",
                    "selected.medium": "5"
                },
                "details": {
                    "phase": [{
                        "value": "2",
                        "timestamp": 1617605301316
                    }]
                }
            },
            {
                "startAt": 1617603849697,
                "endAt": 1617603966378,
                "duration": 116681,
                "selection": {
                    "selected.Speed": "0",
                    "selected.Low": "65535",
                    "selected.Fast": "123",
                    "selected.medium": "5"
                },
                "details": {
                    "phase": [{
                        "value": "2",
                        "timestamp": 1617603849749
                    }]
                }
            }
        ]
```

I need to count how many times selected.Fast has occurred. I am trying with stream and this is what I have written so far

```
List<Map<String, Object>> jsonObj = mapper.readValue(jArr, new TypeReference<List<Map<String, Object>>>(){});
                
Map<String, Long> counted = jsonObj.stream()
        .map(x -> x.get("selection").toString() )
        .collect(Collectors.toList())
        .stream()
        .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Function.identity(), Collectors.counting()));

System.out.println(counted.toString());
```

But I am getting count of all the key inside selection object, and I want count for specific Json key which is `selected.Fast`
For Example
`selected.Fast:"7173" -> occurred - 5times  selected.Fast:"123" -> occurred - 2times`

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you check if this is what you are looking for ?

```
 List<JsonNode> jsonObj = mapper.readValue(jArr, new TypeReference<List<JsonNode>>() {
    });

    Map<String, Long> counted = jsonObj.stream()
            .map(x -> {
                String selection = x.get("selection").get("selected.Fast").asText();
                return "selected.Fast:" + selection;
            }).collect(Collectors.toList())
            .stream()
            .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Function.identity(), Collectors.counting()));

    System.out.println(counted); //{selected.Fast:123=1, selected.Fast:7173=1}
```

**Edit: Without converting to JsonNode**

```
    List<Map<String, Object>> jsonObj = mapper.readValue(jArr, new TypeReference<List<Map<String, Object>>>(){});

    Map<String, Long> counted = jsonObj.stream()
            .map(x -> {
                String selection = ((Map<String,Object>)x.get("selection")).get("selected.Fast").toString();
                return "selected.Fast:" + selection;
            }).collect(Collectors.toList())
            .stream()
            .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Function.identity(), Collectors.counting()));

    System.out.println(counted);
```

**Edit 2: Solution to get count of all the elements inside the selection**

```
    Map<String, Long> counted = jsonObj.stream().flatMap(x -> {
        JsonNode selection = x.get("selection");
        return StreamSupport.stream(Spliterators.spliteratorUnknownSize(selection.fields(), 0), false);
    })
            .map(x -> x.getKey() + ":" + x.getValue()).collect(Collectors.toList())
            .stream()
            .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Function.identity(), Collectors.counting()));
    System.out.println(counted);
```

Comment: Thanks for the response 
There is a error in this line
`String selection = x.get("selection").get("selected.Fast").asText();`
`The method get(int) in the type JsonArray is not applicable for the arguments (String)`

Comment: I am using com.fasterxml.jackson.databind 2.6.7.1, may be there is version mismatch. Which jackson version you are using ?

Comment: I am using 2.8.5

Comment: I think you imported wrong JsonNode or something else is wrong. Here x should be a type of JsonNode (to be precise, com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.node.ObjectNode). Please check this link https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.8/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/JsonNode.html#get(java.lang.String)

Comment: Thanks Found the issue, working now, Thanks for your help

Comment: is there any way to count for other element too inside selection object in a single stream

Comment: assuming selection is the last node, jsonNode.fields() gives you a map of iterator which you need to convert to stream, updated the code

Answer (score 2):

> I need to count how many times selected.Fast has occurred.

Is this what you're after?

```
List<Map<String, Object>> jsonObj = mapper.readValue(jArr, new TypeReference<List<Map<String, Object>>>(){});
                
long count = jsonObj.stream()
        .map(x -> x.get("selection").toString())
        .filter(s -> s.contains("selected.Fast"))
        .count()

System.out.println(count);
```

Comment: Sorry I think my question was not clear, I need how many times
selected.Fast:"7173" -> occurred - 5 times
selected.Fast:"123" -> occurred - 2 times

Answer (score 0):

You can use normally deserialize by jackson library and create object structure like that:

```
    @Setter
    @Getter
    @NoArgsConstructor
    static class Source {

        private long startAt;

        private long endAt;

        private long duration;

        private SourceSelection selection;

        private SourceDetails details;
    }

    @Setter
    @Getter
    @NoArgsConstructor
    static class SourceSelection {

        private long speed;

        private long low;

        private long fast;

        private long medium;
    }

    @Setter
    @Getter
    @NoArgsConstructor
    static class SourceDetails {

        private List<SourcePhase> phase;
    }

    @Setter
    @Getter
    @NoArgsConstructor
    static class SourcePhase {

        private int value;

        private long timestamp;
    }
```

And then you need to deserialize your json to Source.class object:

```
List<Source> sourceList = new ObjectMapper().readValue(
        JSON,
        new ObjectMapper().getTypeFactory().constructCollectionType(List.class, Source.class)
);
```

When `JSON` is your source `json`

And then you can use a standart stream API for mapping, filtering, and counting:

```
    long result = sourceList.stream()
            .map(Source::getSelection)
            .filter(s-> s.getFast() != 0)
            .count();
```

Answer (score 0):

To output information about a field of the specified name in all levels of JSON records that have indefinite number of levels, the Java code will be long and complicated.

You can use SPL, the open-source Java package, to do this. It is easy and only one line of code is enough:

|  | A |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | =json(file("data.json").read()).groups(#4.#3;count(~)).("selected.Fast:\""/#1/""-> occurred -"/#2/"times") |

SPL offers JDBC driver to be invoked by Java. Just store the above SPL script as count.splx and invoke it in Java as you call a stored procedure:

```
…
Class.forName("com.esproc.jdbc.InternalDriver");
con= DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:esproc:local://");
st = con.prepareCall("call count()");
st.execute();
…
```